# link is not working as expected in Mozilla if name of anchor tag is used in href of the link

Tags: html

Below is the link:

```
<a href="#general" id="NoWaitIcon">XXXX</a>
```

Target element is like below:

```
<a name="general"></a>

<span class="orange13b"><traqIntl:message key="General  Settings" /></span>
```

If i click on the link , control should navigate to the span element which is on the same page. It is working fine in chrome and IE but not working in mozilla firefox 34.0.5.

please help me with this one.

Comment: `<a name="general" id="general"></a>`

Comment: adding id attribute is not helping